# Unity DI auto-registration from specific Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to use the Unity Registration by Convention feature. 
I can't figure out how to register from specific assembly/project files with the file ending "Repository".

```
container.RegisterTypes(
       AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(),
       WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
       WithName.Default,
       WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

I've found only this example from a MSDN blog ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/agile/2013/03/12/unity-configuration-registration-by-convention/ ) post and as I understand it, this will search through all projects/assemblies and will look for default naming convention files Class and IClass.

I have a project in my solution named CManager.Repository with repository files ending with *Repository. They are auto-registered.

Any hint or help?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the blog post you're referencing?

Comment: I added ulr to blog post

Comment: You mean classes whose name ends with "Repository", right? Do you have the "CManager.Repository" project references from the composition root project (the project where you use Unity)?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes, classes which ends with Repository example PersonRepository.cs
I setup Unity in CManager.Infrastructure with has reference to CManger.Repository and to web app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **auto-registration** of unity it's better to separate the `Interfaces`and `Repositories` as folder in the repository project with **proper naming convention.**
[image]

If you have all **repositories** under single project then it's not needed to scan for all assemblies. This should register all repositories under project `CManager.Repository`

```
  public static class UnityConfig
   {
     public static void RegisterComponents()
      {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        var repositoryAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .First(a => a.FullName == "CManager.Repository, Version=X.X.X.X, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"); 

        container.RegisterTypes(repositoryAssembly.GetTypes(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);      

        container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
       // ................ register other things is needed
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
     }
  }
```

we have to register unity components on application **startup**, traditionally inside `Global.asax.cs` file. So put `UnityConfig.cs` file on startup project under `App_Start` folder.

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);            
    }      
}
```

and make sure other projects are **linked up** with startup project.

Comment: I have such solution architecture. Web - representation layer. Database - is where I implement context. Entity - where all entities are stored. Repository - repository implemented. Core - basically bll. Infrastructure - this is layer where I implement unity DI. So if I want auto register repo's there how should code look like?

Comment: My DI is configured and working. I can't make auto-register work. Web is linked to infrastructure. Question is how to scan from specific assembly for specific classes

Comment: `var repositoryAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();` this will find all linked assemblies from current assembly  and you can filter then. No need to find specific class. It will register all Repository class based on naming convention.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked! Maybe you know how I can specifi classes that end's with *Repository ? Because in Repository project I have IService interface that I don't want to register. It is for internal project purpose.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me on a enterprise web-api that I have been working on for months now. It has an n-tier architecture with a data layer that has .cs files that end with 'Repository'. While I agree with the other post the Interfaces should be seperated, in my web-api they are not implemented in this way.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using Unity.WebApi;

namespace Blah.Endpoints.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
    /// </summary>
    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers
            RegisterTypes(container);
            // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configured Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
        /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
        /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
        /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {

            container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
                WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                WithName.Default,
                null,                //WithLifetime IF we want to change the lifetime aspect aka Singletons 
                null,//GetMembers,
                false
                );
        }


    }
}
```

This setup has usually works for my team. Sometimes we still get classes that throw unity errors for no apparent reason. For those we do something like this;

```
public class WcfServiceFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            //Attach hook for AOP attributes
            container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

            // register all your components with the container here
            // container
            //    .RegisterType<IService1, Service1>()
            //    .RegisterType<DataContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

            container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
                WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                WithName.Default,
                null,                //WithLifetime IF we want to change the lifetime aspect aka Singletons 
                GetMembers,
                false
                );

            container.RegisterType<IPaymentService, PaymentService>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentManager, PaymentManager>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentMethodRepository, PaymentMethodRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentWithdrawScheduleRepository, PaymentWithdrawScheduleRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentPreEnrollmentRepository, PaymentPreEnrollmentRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<ISharedLoanDataRepository<tblPaymentMethod>, SharedLoanDataRepository<tblPaymentMethod>>();
            container.RegisterType<ISharedLoanDataRepository<tblPaymentWithdrawSchedule>, SharedLoanDataRepository<tblPaymentWithdrawSchedule>>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentWithdrawScheduleOffSetTypeRepository, PaymentWithdrawScheduleOffSetTypeRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentMethodTypeRepository, PaymentMethodTypeRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentWithdrawScheduleFrequencyTypeRepository, PaymentWithdrawScheduleFrequencyTypeRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentCustomerNotificationRepository, PaymentCustomerNotificationRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<ITraceLogger, TraceLogger>();
            container.RegisterType<IPaymentWithdrawScheduleCancelReasonRepository, PaymentWithdrawScheduleCancelReasonRepository>();
        }

        private IEnumerable<InjectionMember> GetMembers(Type type)
        {
            var list = new List<InjectionMember>();
            list.Add(new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(type.ToString()));
            list.Add(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(type.ToString()));
            return list;
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps

Regards.