# Register many types at once in Unity Container Config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, unity-container

We are using some services in unity that need to be added manualy everytime. The only problem is that this is easy to forget.
Here's how we construct the container:

```
 container.RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<emplabsq>, EmplabsqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<requhrap>, RequhrapService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<emplabsk>, EmplabskService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<lettrept>, LettreptService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<lettdocs>, LettdocsService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<emplrqti>, EmplrqtiService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<emplplrq>, EmplplrqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<empltrrq>, EmpltrrqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<emplfurq>, EmplfurqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<emploprq>, EmploprqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<emplqtrq>, EmplqtrqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<emplclrq>, EmplclrqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<addrstrq>, AddrstrqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<addrphrq>, AddrphrqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IWorkflowEntityService<addrmlrq>, AddrmlrqService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
```

Is there any way we can simplify this and auto generate this code?

Thanks all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498934/unity-di-auto-registration-from-specific-assembly

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way. Not sure if it's the right way btw.

```
 var type = typeof(IWorkflowable);
        var workflowables = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.Name != type.Name);
        foreach (var @class in workflowables)
        {
            var serviceClassName = @class.Name.First().ToString().ToUpper() + @class.Name.Substring(1);
            Type serviceClass = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(serviceClassName) && x.Name.EndsWith("Service")).FirstOrDefault();

            IWorkflowable instance = (IWorkflowable)Activator.CreateInstance(@class);

            var dataType = new Type[] { @class };
            var genericBase = typeof(IWorkflowEntityService<>);
            var combinedType = genericBase.MakeGenericType(dataType);

            container.RegisterType(combinedType, serviceClass);
        }
```